# Program that counts most and least common non-space characters

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that basically has an inputted string and what the program is supposed to do is to output the character that occurs the most and says how many times it occurs. It also outputs the character that occurs the least and says how many times it occurs.

I'm having trouble getting started with this as I'm doing this in part of a summer college course so its a whole semesters class in 6 weeks so the class goes by pretty fast. Could someone please explain the logic behind this for me so I could get started?

We haven't learned many different methods so if you could stick to basic python programming that would be nice. <- Like while loops and for loops we learned, lists, tuples, strings etc. We didn't learn any thing else..

Thanks

Comment: `dict` are a fundamental aspect of Python. If you haven't covered them after 6 weeks, your teacher is not doing a good job. It's possible to solve your question with just lists and strings, however it will be extremely inefficient and ugly code. If you'll allow us to use `ord()` you can still regain some efficiency but it will still be ugly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like a challenge. No complex data structures, just simple loops and ifs. If this is too complex then your teacher has done a bad job!

```
w = "This is the song that doesn't end; yes it goes on and on my friend."
max_letter = w[0]
min_letter = w[0]
max = w.count(w[0])
min = w.count(w[0])
for c in w:
    if c is not " ":
        if w.count(c) > max:
            max_letter = c
            max = w.count(c)
        if w.count(c) < min:
            min_letter = c
            min = w.count(c)

print max, max_letter
print min, min_letter

>>> 7 n
>>> 1 T
```

@Rohan asked how I built this up, and its only fair I describe it. *Basicaly, its an exercise in answering questions, and making new questions as I go through.*

**What are the maximum and minimum occurring letters?** The first thing you know is you need to find and print some things. Those things are the minimum and maximum letters. At the start of everything, I know the first letter will be both, so lets start there. *It should be said though, what happens if the string is empty?*

```
max_letter = w[0]
min_letter = w[0]
```

**If these letters are the most and least occurring how often do they appear?** Now, I know I need to keep track of extra information, and since I decided the first letter is the minimum and maximum set the count of this letter to be the `min` and `max`.

```
max = w.count(w[0])
min = w.count(w[0])
```

**How can I know that these letters really are the most and least common?** Well, I need to check all of the letters, I can do this in a loop:

```
for c in w:
```

**Is this current character something I am checking for?** In this case, I only want things that aren't spaces, but I could check for anything here.

```
    if c is not " ":
```

**Is this current letter the most common?** Not sure, so check it against the maximum, if it is then update what the letter with the maximum count is, and what the maximum count is.

```
        if w.count(c) > max:
            max_letter = c
            max = w.count(c)
```

**Same for the least common...**

```
        if w.count(c) < min:
            min_letter = c
            min = w.count(c)
```

**Then print out what I found out**

```
print max, max_letter
print min, min_letter
```

**Can this algorithm be better?** Yes. This algorithm checked if `'n'` was the maximum letter 7 times. The answer never changes. It also runs through the string many times -

- Once per letter in the for loop
- In a simple counting algorithm, it would run through again in each iteration to get the count.

Comment: Probably should be `if str.isalnum()`, but even that filters some nonspace punctuation that arguably should be counted.

Comment: Hi I have a stupid question, but what is c? Is it like a variable in the the string w? It doesn't have to be defined beforehand right?

Comment: `c`'s value will change with each iteration of that `for` loop.  it's each individual character in the input string, `w`.

Comment: `c` is declared as the iterated variable and only has scope for that for loop. It is set to each letter in the string in turn.

Comment: @BrianCain technically punctuation should be counted according to the question, so now it just compares against a space. Besides, wouldn't want to use any of those pesky built-ins.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr can I just ask you a question: When I'm given questions like these, what are the steps I should take to solve it? Because whenever I get these questions, I'm always so stumped and overwhelmed by what to do

Comment: @Rohan, get your feet wet with [Code like a Pythonista](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html) just to learn the idioms of the language.  But if you get stuck, maybe google for `python count characters` or seek out SO again!  ;)

Comment: @Rohan, I broke down the code for you that helps explain how I built up that solution.

Comment: Thank you so much Lego Stormtroopr, not only does that edition explain the code beautifully, but now I know in what way to think in order to solve new problems! Thank you so much for taking the extra time to help me out!

Comment: Thats cool, but there is a lot of better answers that could do this better or faster. **Keep their answers in mind when you are writing to do a job not get a passing grade**

Answer (score 7):

```
from collections import Counter
the_string = "This is a string!"
Counter(x for x in the_string if not x.isspace()).most_common()
```

Here is a way to get started without Counters/dicts/etc.

```
>>> the_string = "This is a string!"
>>> A = [0] * 256
>>> for x in the_string:
...     if not x.isspace():
...         A[ord(x)] += 1
...
```

`ord()` maps each character onto a position in `A`

```
>>> A
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

You easily can find *one* of the most common characters like this

```
>>> chr(A.index(max(A)))
'i'
```

The minimum is more complicated, since we need the minimum that isn't `0`

```
>>> chr(A.index(min(x for x in A if x)))
'!'
```

Ok, you probably aren't comfortable with max and min and generator expressions, but you should be able to work out for to do it with a `for` loop after 6 weeks

Comment: It's not that it's **wrong.**  It's that someone whose only a few weeks into the program would get many looks if they suddenly used *the right* methods.

Comment: So now we are downvoting correct answers now because we don't want to raise eyebrows? Are students not allowed to look for better solutions than they have been taught these days?

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't exist to do peoples homework. @Rohan wants to post his entire syllabus and have someone write code against that, they should close the question as tool localised and hire a tutor. This is an excellent answer, that answers the *question* perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html):

```
>>> Counter(''.join("This is a string!".split())).most_common()
[('i', 3), ('s', 3), ('a', 1), ('!', 1), ('g', 1), ('h', 1), ('n', 1), ('r', 1), ('T', 1), ('t', 1)]
```

Or, for learning purposes, you can use a for-loop, along with a dictionary to keep count:

```
mystring = ''.join("This is a string!".split())
mydict = {}
for char in mystring:
    if char not in mydict:
        mydict[char] = 1
    else:
        mydict[char] += 1

print mydict
# {'a': 1, '!': 1, 'g': 1, 'i': 3, 'h': 1, 'n': 1, 's': 3, 'r': 1, 'T': 1, 't': 1}
print max(mydict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
# i
```

[`max()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) gets the maximum value from an object. We pass it a key argument, because we are working with a dictionary.

`mydict.items()` returns a list of tuples, with the key and value in one tuple.

`key=lambda x: x[1]` is telling python to look through the second item in the tuple, because that is the number that we want. Finally, `[0]` is used to get the key.

`mydict.items` looks like this:

> [('a', 1), ('!', 1), ('g', 1), ('i', 3), ('h', 1), ('n', 1), ('s', 3), ('r', 1), ('T', 1), ('t', 1)]

It's like the unpacked version of a dictionary.

---

For the least common, simply use `min()` :). Isn't python fun?

Comment: **Technically yes**, but wouldn't there be some eyebrows raised if someone six weeks in started to use library methods?

Comment: yes I haven't learned anything like this so I don't think I'd be allowed to use this.....

Comment: @Makoto, are you serious? I've taught people enough Python in _one day_ to be able to do real work.

Comment: @gnibbler:  Teaching someone in the field is worlds removed from teaching someone in the classroom.

Answer (score 1):

This is solved straightforwardly with using a dictionary and some methods around retrieving the key.  Dictionaries are guaranteed to have unique keys, but their order isn't guaranteed.

```
d = dict()
w = "This is the song that doesn't end; yes it goes on and on my friend."
for letter in w:
    if d.get(letter) is not None:
        d[letter] += 1
    else:
        d[letter] = 1
```

I'd like to leave the rest for you to solve, as getting the count of elements was the largest hurdle.  You can get the max and min from this relatively easy, as well.

Comment: @Rohan `dict()` is equivalent to making an empty dictionary, i.e, `{}`

Comment: `dict()` is a dictionary, which is shorthand for an empty dictionary `{}`.

Comment: You lose the ability to do key-value mappings easily if it's a list.  You don't *want* a list.  You want a way to count the values out with respect to a given letter.

Comment: `letter not in d` is preferable to `d.get(letter) is not None`

Comment: @Makoto He doesn't *want* a dict either, he should want to use something thats part of the standard library... like a `counter`

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr, unless the point of the exercise is not "how to leverage the batteries-included with python" but instead "how to think like a computer scientist: implementing simple algorithms with python."

Comment: @BrianCain considering that using dict isn't an option, then I'd say that isn't the plan. Lists, associative arrays and tuples are the 3 major data structures and the OP isn't allowed to use a third of them.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr, I can't speak for the submitter but I can say without a doubt that I took courses where the teacher cared not which language we used to implement the algorithms, but that he would hold it against us if we decided to not implement the subject matter from the course and instead leverage someone else's.  Those are common data structures in `python` yet you could technically implement everything with bitwise `&`, `|`, and `~`.